# How to do string aritmatic operation in Pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

Here's the pandas code

`datamonthly["period"] = ((datamonthly["year"]*100).astype(int) + datamonthly["month"].astype(int) ).astype(str)`

How to do something like this in Pyspark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work in a Spark dataframe:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
    

datamonthly = datamonthly.withColumn(
    "period",
    ((col("year") * 100).cast(IntegerType()) + col("month").cast(IntegerType())).cast(
        StringType()
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

datamonthly.select(
    f.concat(f.col('year') * 100, f.col('month')).alias('period')
)
```

Comment: the new column name is not saved